# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append' when appending to list in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append

I keep getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tabba/PycharmProjects/erle_loops/Hobbies.py", line 9, in <module>
    hobbies = hobbies.append(hobby)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

The purpose of this program is to add hobbies to a list

My code:

```
hobby = ''
hobbies = []
no_room_left = False
room = 3
count = 0
while not no_room_left:
    if count<room:
        hobby = str(input("Enter hobby"))
        hobbies = hobbies.append(hobby)
        count+=1
print(hobbies)
```

Answer (score 7):

[`append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) returns `None` and changes the list, so use `append` by itself (should not set it):

```
# List would be None
hobbies = hobbies.append(hobby)

# Good
hobbies.append(hobby)
```

Code:

```
hobby = ''
hobbies = []
no_room_left = False
room = 3
count = 0
while not no_room_left:
    if count<room:
        hobby = str(input("Enter hobby"))
        hobbies.append(hobby)
        count+=1
print(hobbies)
```